# React onClick callAll functions syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I recently started to learn React in more depth, and something is triggering me because I cant understand this syntax (I know is a ES6 thing)

So I got this component, lets call it  and this component will receive an onClick function as a prop with one param, so we have <Component onClick={() => handleClick("clicked")}/>

This Component, has a callAll function and is implemented like this

```
const callAll = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args))

const Component = ({children: child}) => {
return React.cloneElement(child, {
    onClick: callAll(() => setIsOpen(true), child.props.onClick),
  })
}
```

My question is where does the ...args come from, in the sense of how does the inner function of 'callAll' receive all the args of each specific function magically just by typing '...args'?

I hope I explained myself, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That `const callAll`... statement creates an arrow function that creates an arrow function when you call it. In traditional function syntax it would look like this:

```
function callAll(...fns) {
    return function(...args) {
        fns.forEach(function(fn) {
            fn && fn(...args);
        });
    };
}
```

So the argument(s) you pass `callAll` are the functions to call (which are gathered up into the `fns` array). When you call it, you get back a function that will call all of those functions with whatever arguments it's called with (which are gathered up into the `args` array):

```
const callLogAndError = callAll(console.log, console.error);
// fns −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
callLogAndError(1, 2, 3); 
// args −−−−−−−−^^^^^^^
```

Live example:

```js
const callAll = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args));

const callLogAndError = callAll(console.log, console.error);
// fns −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
callLogAndError(1, 2, 3); 
// args −−−−−−−−^^^^^^^
```

So later, in the `onclick`:

```
callAll(() => setIsOpen(true), child.props.onClick)
```

That creates a function that will call these two functions with the arguments it receives (which, with `onClick`, would be just the event object for the event):

1. `() => setIsOpen(true)`
2. `child.props.onClick`

That `onClick` could also have been written like this, without `callAll`:

```
onClick: (event) => {
    setIsOpen(true);
    child.props.onClick(event);
}
```

Comment: So, if I understand only the event object will be passed? If I use the component like in my example <Component onClick = {() => handleClick("clicked")}/> , the handleClick function will be called by callAll but the "clicked" param would be lost?

If not, what I do not understand is how the ...args spread "exctracts" the params of each function call

Comment: @SantiArias - The call to `callAll` creates a function. Whatever *calls* that function is what sets the `args` that the function sees. So if you hook it up directly (`onClick={theFunctionFromCallAll}`), it'll receive the event object. If you hook it up indirectly (`onClick={() => theFunctionFromCallAll("click");}`), it'll receive `"click"`.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now, thank you for your time!